# What do the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{243}$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

Since $243 = 3^5$ and $3$ is a prime number we can construct the field $\mathbb{F}_{243}$ with $243$ elements, by taking an irreducible polynomial $f$ of degree $5$, then we get: $\mathbb{F}_{243}\cong \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(f(x))$. But is there a way to explicitly compute the elements of this field? Or a way to see more of the structure of the field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can compute $\mathbb{F}_{243}\cong \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(f(x))$ explicitly.  Just pick an irreducible polynomial $f$ and begin.

I would first pick some element of the quotient and start computing its powers mod $f(x)$.  If it reaches $1$ before the $242$'th power, then it is not a primitive element, and I would select a new element of the quotient that I had not previously seen and begin again.

Eventually you will find a primitive element $\alpha$ of the field, so that every nonzero element of the field is a power of $\alpha$.

There is not much to "the structure" of a finite field beyond its primitive elements.

Comment: +1 Your answer mentions the multiplicative structure. For the additive structure, it is worth noting that we can view this field as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_3$ and hence we have a vector space isomorphism $\mathbb{F}_{243}\cong \mathbb{F}_3^n$ with $n =\dim_{\mathbb{F}_3}( \mathbb{F}_{243})$. In particular, this is an isomorphism of additive groups.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Yes indeed. I always found it interesting that for finite fields the additive structure was "as discrete as possible" while the multiplicative structure is the opposite.

Comment: @rschwieb I can only write this isomorphism $\mathbb{F}_{243} \cong \mathbb{F}_{3}^{5}$ if I am looking at the additive structure, right? Can I do something similar for the multiplicative structure, without computing the elements of the field?

Comment: $\mathbb F_{243}\cong \mathbb F_3^5$ as $F_3$ vector spaces, yes.  $\mathbb F_{243}^\times\cong \mathbb Z_{242}$ as abelian groups. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, thank you :)

Comment: As a shortcut, you don't need to calculate all powers up to $\alpha^{242}$, it's sufficient just to check $\alpha^{121} \ne 1$ and $\alpha^{22} \ne 1$.  And then, those could be calculated as e.g. $\alpha^{121} = (\alpha^{60})^2 \alpha$, $\alpha^{60} = (\alpha^{30})^2$, etc. keeping it modded out by $f$ at each step.

Comment: That is indeed a good trick to keep in mind.

Comment: As a *very* old hand at this kind of thing, I want to commend you for this answer, and the commenters for their useful additions. The only addition I might’ve made concerned the question of finding an irreducible quintic. Broadly speaking, almost anything should work, but if you have a quintic you want to check, say $\Bbb F_3[x]/(f(x))$, you can just calculate $x^{242}$ and see whether it’s $1$. If not, try another $f$. Unless $f$ has repeated factors, the quotient ring will always be a sum of fields of degree $<5$, so no element of order $242$ (except those few that square to $1$).